# Is arcore a good fit for "observatory" type of scenes

Tags: arcore

An observatory shows a sphere from the inside in which the user can look around to see various objects attached to the "sky". I am interested in the sceneform apis but am not sure if arcore would be suited for tracking when it can not recognize any landscape features. Is arcore a good fit for such a scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general ARCore and Sceneform appears to be set up to detect 'planes' and then to attach anchor and renderable objects to those planes.

Your application sounds like it will not have planes, so you may find a lot of the ARCore mechanisms, documentation and examples are not going to be as helpful to you as you might want.

However, it is possible to attach an 'anchor' and renderable object to a point if you have the correct co-ordinates.

The following code, from this discussion https://github.com/google-ar/arcore-android-sdk/issues/110, allows you to place an object in front of the camera for example:

```js
mAnchors.add(session.createAnchor(
    frame.getCamera().getPose()
        .compose(Pose.makeTranslation(0, 0, -1f))
        .extractTranslation()))
```

If you experiment you will find you can adjust the x, y a z co-ordinates in the Pose.makeTranslation method to place objects where you need them.

You don't need to use the camera as above also, so long as you have a pose you can add a renderable object - see example below:

```js
Frame frame = arFragment.getArSceneView().getArFrame();
myAnchor = session.createAnchor(myPose.extractTranslation());
myAnchorNode = new AnchorNode(myAnchor);
myAnchorNode.setRenderable(myRenderable);
myAnchorNode.setParent(arFragment.getArSceneView().getScene());
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I agree on your assumption that the library has the plane detection as one of its key characteristics. My hope is that it is also suited to keep good track of its current orientation by using some visual clues in addition to the compass/accelerometer.

Comment: @Moritz - from my experiments on a Pixel I have found it does for my needs for simple non plane attached renderables, but your application may need a higher degree of accuracy. If you succeed it might be worth adding your own answer here also with some details, as I think others would be interested.

Comment: I will play around and with it and see where i end up. I'll let you know.